# Python: How do I scrape ESPN for game matchups

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, iterator

Fairly new to programming, apologies is the question is broad.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def data():
    League = ['nba', 'nfl', 'mlb']
    url = f"http://www.espn.com/{League[0]}/schedule"
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    date = soup.find('h2',{'class':'table-caption'})
    return date.string
```

This is what I have so far, but what I'd like to be able to do is scrape the matchups for this day so it comes out as:

```
>>> 'Los Angeles Lakers at Charlotte Bobcats 7:00PM'
>>> 'Boston Celtics at Detroit Pistons 7:00PM'
```

I see all of the information is in there, but I don't know how iterate through the rows, and to pull the data when it's not specifically as a string. I understand this is broad, and a lot to ask for. Sorry in advance!

Comment: Learn about XPath and using web development tools like e.g. Firebug for Firefox to find out how to find and address specific data on a website.

Comment: Does XPath work better than request? Or am I able to tailor it more?

Comment: XPath is a way to address specific items of a HTML web page. It may be helpful but depending on complexitiy `soup.find` may be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think SO community is sometimes too harsh to beginners.

Here is a way for you to locate the table results and extract home and away team names:

```
for row in soup.select("table.schedule tbody tr"):
    home_team, away_team = row.select(".team-name")

    print(home_team.get_text(), away_team.get_text())
```

The idea here is to use a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to locate table rows, iterate over every row and get the two elements with `team-name` class.

---

Overall the process of coming up with something like this is relatively straightforward:

- inspect the desired element in browser developer tools
- think about the things you can use to find this element - something that uniquely identifies this element (e.g. look at that super explicit `team-name` class)
- write (in this case) Python/BeautifulSoup code to try and locate this element
- reiterate until works

That's just high level but hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick question, how could I get the for loop to stop iterating at the end of the current day, so it gets just those days games?

Comment: @DG.Finance sure, the `table.schedule tbody tr` needs to be adjusted to look into the first table only, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Apologies for not being able to upvote your answer, looks like SO won't let me yet. I looked into the elements, and can't find anything distinctly unique to adjust that recommendation, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @DG.Finance I think if you loop over it as `for row in soup.select_one("table.schedule").select("tbody tr"):`, it should work.